# Problema com mPDF e CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

Tenho código no `Controller` abaixo que está funcionando perfeitamente, porém eu quero setar meu próprio título e quando eu tento com `SetTitle()` ele me retorna esse erro:

> Call to a member function SetTitle() on null

```
public function gerar() 
{   
    $this->load->helper('funcoes_helper');
    $this->load->helper('financeiro_helper');
    $this->load->helper('array_helper');
    $this->load->model('cadastro_model');
    $this->load->helper('funcoes');

    //load the view and saved it into $html variable
    $html= $this->load->view('novo/contrato', true);

    //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
    $pdfFilePath = "contrato.pdf";

    $mpdf =$this->load->library('m_pdf','m_pdf');
    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('m_pdf','m_pdf');

    $mpdf->pdf->SetTitle('My Title');

    //generate the PDF from the given html
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

    //download it.
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath,'I');       
}
```

Meu arquivo `.php`:

```
<?php 
    if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

    class M_pdf 
    {
        public $param;
        public $pdf;

        public function __construct($param = "'c', 'A4-L'")
        {
            $this->param =$param;
            $this->pdf = new mPDF($this->param);
        }
    }
?>
```

Quero setar meu título para "Contrato". Como faço isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você trocar:

```
$mpdf->m_pdf->pdf->SetTitle('My Title');
```

Para

```
$this->m_pdf->pdf->SetTitle('My Title');
```